# SQLite - find all data and its dependent data that is referenced in another row

Tags: sql, inner-join, sql-like

I have one very large table with a number of rows. I would like to be able to find all data and its dependent data that is referenced in another row.

I would like to know how can I retrieve all data that is contained in one row that is referenced in another row. e.g.

```
    Table:
    K_T     Doc_type    Doc_rule

    1       INVOICE1    This is a invoice
    1       INVOICE2    This is another invoice check
    1       INVOICE3    INVOICE1 & INVOICE2
    2       DEPO1       This is a deposit *()%^
    2       DEPO2       This is also a deposit && other stuff{} +more things
    2       ACC1        INVOICE1 & DEPO1
    2       ACC2        INVOICE3 & DEPO1 & DEPO2
```

So I would like to be able to get the following output.

```
    1       INVOICE3    INVOICE1 & INVOICE2
    2       ACC1        INVOICE1 & DEPO1
    2       ACC2        INVOICE3 & DEPO1 & DEPO2
```

I would like to be able to output the doc_types and there dependent doc_rules.
I have tried using a self join and a left join but I cannot get either a "like" or "contains" to work in a SQL statement on SQL lite. Here is a sample of what I've tried.

```
    select t1.K_T, t1.doc_type, t2.doc_rule
    from Documents as t1
    inner join Documents as t2
    on t1.doc_type like t2.doc_rule
    group by t2.doc_type
```

Any input would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the `SELF JOIN` is what you need (but please correct me if I'm wrong)

Recommend having a look on there to understand how self joins work in SQL-Lite:
[self join](http://www.sqlitetutorial.net/sqlite-self-join/)

Answer (score 0):

Your output is returned by this query:

```
select t.*
from t
where doc_rule like '% & %';
```

Comment: Thanks for the input, but there are special characters also used in the field Doc_rule, so if I do a like for "&" I will also extract unwanted records. I just updated the table sample above for hopefully better clarification